# How do you create the Commonest function

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, implementation-details

How does the `Commonest` function work?  How can I implement that functionality without using that command?

Comment: What have you tried?  And why do that, when there is such a useful function already written?  Yours will certainly be less efficient, and will make a bit more difficult the sharing of your code.  What is wrong with the function as it stands?

Comment: re _how it works_: try `Trace[Commonest[data]] // Column`.

Comment: Not sure why close votes. Seems a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 12):

```
commonest = Keys @* MaximalBy[N] @* Counts

commonest[{a, a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {a}
> ```

```
commonest[{a, a, b, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {a, b}
> ```

```
commonest[{a, a, b, b, c, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {a, b, c}
> ```

Also

```
commonest2 = Flatten @* Map[Most] @* MaximalBy[Last] @* Tally

commonest3 = Map[First] @* MaximalBy[Length] @* Gather

commonest4 = Map[First] @* MaximalBy[Length] @* Split @* Sort

commonest5 = Apply[Pick[##, Max @ #2] &] @* Transpose @* Tally
```

etc...

#### Implementation details of `Commonest`:

You can get a notebook that contains the definition of `Commonest` using

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Commonest]
```

If you follow the links in this notebook, you find that for `List` input the result is produced by the function `` Statistics`DescriptiveDump`oCommonest `` and its definition is

```
Statistics`DescriptiveDump`oCommonest[Pattern[list, Blank[]]] := 
  Block[{c, mc, val, freq},
   c = Tally@list;
   freq = c[[All, 2]];
   mc = Max@freq;
   Pick[c[[All, 1]], freq, mc]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {c, c, c, b, b, b, a, a, d, e};
```

Using `SequenceCases` to split

```
SequenceCases[Sort @ list, {x_ ..}]
```

{{a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d}, {e}}

A clone of `Commonest` which accepts its 2nd parameter

```
com[list_, n_ : Automatic] :=
 Module[{sc = ReverseSortBy[Length] @ SequenceCases[Sort @ list, {x_ ..}]},
  (* Sort single elements in ascending order *)
  sc = SubsetMap[Sort, sc, -Count[sc, {_}] ;; -1];
  First /@ If[n === Automatic, MaximalBy[Length] @ sc, sc[[1 ;; UpTo @ n]]]]
```

Test ist

```
test = {{list}, {list, 1}, {list, 2}, {list, 3}, {list, 4}, {list, 5}};

com @@@ test // TableForm
```

[image]

```
com @@@ test == Commonest @@@ test
```

True

Comment: +1 I tried a few alternatives, but I didn't understand how to sort the results to match the order that `Commonest` uses. I really liked your proposal.

Comment: Thanks you, regarding the complicated sorting I will probably ask a question in the next days.